# Rails UK cities and districts gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

People have asked this before but are usually told to use Carmen, which is no longer maintained.

The Countries gem has something close to what I want, except there are no districts, like 'Ibrox', 'Mount Florida' or 'Dagenham'.

Does anyone know of a gem that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that gem with UK cities is exists but you can try to use CSV file with GB cities from [here](http://www.geonames.org/export/).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll find something there.

Comment: Thanks for this resource. Sometimes, technically "off topic" questions can prove invaluable.